# ajax been skipped when called again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ok, so my ajax as follow:

```
      $.ajax({
            url: "CheckOut/getCartFromClient/",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(list),
```

which basically send cart items from localstorage to server, now when user edit items, i manage to update the localstorage correctly , however when sending again to the server, the ajax called be skipped and server don't have the updated cart version !?

the issue is the ajax call only work once, the second, third time it always been skipped !?

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I don't think the pertinent part of the code is shown here. Are you sure the execution reaches your ajax call a second time? Try putting in a breakpoint to see if it gets there.

Comment: @Tushar am not clear if i understand your comment !?

Comment: @BillyMoon i placed the breakpoint, it reach it but does not go through it it skip the hall ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your ajax call under a separate function, if not put it in a function like:

```
function updateCart(list){
$.ajax({
        url: "CheckOut/getCartFromClient/",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(list),
success: function(response){
//do your stuff
},
error:function(err){
//get error
}
```

})

Debugging:
-- Check your data in list items

Hope this helps!

Comment: Try Ariex's tip as well i.e. cache:false

Comment: again it doesn't fire again ,,! i basically call this ajax to store my cart in session. so when edit the ajax doesn't get called and the session cart is outdated !

Answer (score 1):

this may related to caching issue, try add a `cache: false` option in ajax call